# Prove or disprove this big Omega proposition

Tags: big-o

If a function `f₁` is in `O(f₂)`, does it mean f₁ is in `Ω(f₂)`? I am confused because of the equality case.

Comment: please, describe more clearly

Answer (score 0):

No, for instance x = O(x^2), but x != BigOmega(x^2).

Answer (score 0):

If `f` is in `O(g)`, it is not necessary in `Ω(g)` too.

E.g. `2n²+n` is in `O(n³)` and in `O(n²)`. It is also in `Ω(n²)`, but not in `Ω(n³)`.

If `f` is in `O(g)` and `Ω(g)` this simplified to "`f` is in `Θ(g)`".